# Can't find "Find my iPhone" app on OS X

Tags: macos, icloud, find-my-iphone

I have attempted all the suggestions listed in [Apps on my MacBook Pro](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/98000/apps-on-my-macbook-pro/) but I still can't  find the app I am looking for: Find my iPhone.

I have checked Applications, Downloads, Spotlight, Finder, and Launchpad.

I went to download it, iTunes says I have already downloaded it, have tried everything to find it on my computer. I can't find it and I cannot apparently download it again. I am completely stumped with this one and desperately need to find my phone.

Answer (score 8):

There is no native Find my iPhone OS X app.

You mention that you have downloaded the app using iTunes, in which case you have downloaded the iOS app. The app will show in iTunes and will only be available on iOS devices.

To access Find my iPhone on OS X, you need to go to [iCloud.com](http://www.icloud.com/#find).

Answer (score 4):

Open Safari or another web browser and go to:

- https://www.icloud.com/#find

I believe you can also use Linux and Windows browsers to locate devices through iCloud but haven't tested that recently. The app you downloaded in iTunes only runs once you sync it to an iOS device and won't help locate a lost device from your Mac.